# How to keep terminal open after launching desktop file

Tags: unity, python, gnome-terminal

I'm running a python script and its only output is to the terminal.

The problem is, when launched from a desktop file, the terminal closes before I can scroll through the output to read it.

What's a quick way to fix this?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Account Balances
Path=/opt/deployed_code/AccountBalances
Exec=python3.9 -m account_balances
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=/opt/deployed_code/AccountBalances/icons/main_icon.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing .desktop file Exec line to this may be solve your problem? Keeps 100 seconds for gnome-terminal (replace gnome-terminal to another if you using else.)

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'python3.9 -m account_balances; sleep 100'
```

[image]

Comment: The terminal window does stay open.
Now the path is broken. In my original question, I ran the command from:
`Path=/opt/deployed_code/AccountBalances`
The package `account_balances` is installed in the Path folder. It's dependencies are installed in a `venv` folder.

Comment: Okey, so can you try this? (Not tested)

Exec=gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'cd /opt/deployed_code/AccountBalances;sleep 1; python3.9 -m account_balances; sleep 100'

Comment: I tried the above solution ^^ and It works. I also found a workaround by making a run.sh bash file that contains: `read -p "Press Enter to close this window"`

Comment: ...or directly add the same functionality to your python script.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click the file and find "keep open" in the advanced properties menu. This should automatically adjust the contents of the desktop file.
I believe the entry is `TerminalOptions=\s--noclose`, but since I am currently working on KDE, not Gnome, I can not verify.