# How to view terminal output from script initiated from .desktop custom application launcher

Tags: gnome, scripts, launcher, gnome-terminal, .desktop

I created a basic `ls.sh` script with the following body:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
ls
```

and I was sure to allow execute permissions `chmod +x ls.sh`. I tested `ls.sh` in my terminal and it works fine. I went ahead and created a `ls.desktop` entry in `~/.local/share/applications/` with the following body:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=ls.sh
Exec=ls.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Programming;
```

I then press my `Super` key, start typing `ls.sh`, select it from my Ubuntu GNOME default launcher, and nothing happens. There's no output from `ls` printed to my terminal. **How do I get the output to print to my terminal?** Or a newly launched terminal?

And let me add that I went ahead and created another script and desktop entry with whiptail, and whiptail does indeed launch when I press my Super key, start typing `ls-whiptail.sh` and select it from my Ubuntu GNOME default launcher. So it appears I'm doing everything "right". I just need to determine how to see the terminal output from my scripts when initialized through the GNOME .desktop application launcher.

**ls-whiptail.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -x
if whiptail --yesno "Are you sure you want to run this 'ls' command?" 10 40; then
    ls
else
    whiptail --msgbox "You did not run the 'ls' command." 10 40
fi
```

**ls-whiptail.sh desktop entry**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=ls-whiptail.sh
Exec=ls-whiptail.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Programming;
```

Comment: I suspect you need a long-running command after the `ls`, otherwise the default `gnome-terminal` behavior is to exit immediately after the command completes - see for example [How to keep terminal open after launching desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324527/how-to-keep-terminal-open-after-launching-desktop-file)

Comment: ... Also, where did you place the `ls.sh` file? is its parent directory present in your search path `$PATH`?  ... `whiptail` is an executable that is already in your search path and that's part of why it works.

Comment: @steeldriver that's the answer, you might as well post it. I just tested and the OP's script works if we add a `sleep`.

Comment: @steeldriver I also think it's worth an answer ... @terdon it also can be a `read` like e.g. in  `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'ls; read'` or a shell replacement like e.g. in `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'ls; exec bash'` ... etc.

Comment: `read` makes it hang, @Raffa. And `exec bash` does too. I haven't managed to find a good solution yet. But then I don't really understand what the point of doing this instead of opening a terminal is so...

Comment: @terdon Sure `read` hangs until you press Enter, then it closes the terminal and replacing the shell indeed provides you with a running shell ... Those are alternatives in addition to `sleep` ... GUI window is an alternative as well `bash -c 'ls | zenity --text-info'` ... I don't know which one might be more suitable in which use case, but it's always good to provide alternatives if the final goal isn't really clearly determined, isn't it?

Comment: Then please post an answer, @Raffa, I must be doing something wrong because neither `Exec=gnome-terminal -- bash -c "/home/terdon/scripts/ls.sh; exec bash"` nor `Exec=gnome-terminal -- bash -c "/home/terdon/scripts/ls.sh; read"` leave me with a usable prompt.

Comment: @terdon Ah ... I guess because your `ls.sh` script is run in a sub-shell that is actually still will close returning back to the other parent shell of it i.e. the one forked for the command string ... Why not try adding either `read` or `exec bash` to the end of `ls.sh` scriptfile itself to hold that shell with the output ... I hope it'll work ... I mean It should work that way :-)

Comment: Ah yes, that works! Post an answer, @Raffa!

Comment: I have a feeling that either you @terdon or steeldriver will post an answer that I will enjoy reading, so I'm waiting for that and I'm on my phone right now :-D

Comment: @Raffa I'm going to take a back seat here - I haven't actually tried the proposed solutions irl

Comment: @steeldriver LOL ... We can't be all in the back seats with no show ... I've done it ... See where I'm wrong and let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you know that `ls` as you put it is a useless example as it will always list files under your home directory unless you specify an argument to it or a working directory to the terminal ... and that you know `Exec=ls.sh` is not optimal and you better use something like `Exec=/full/path/to/ls.sh` ... also not discussing your `ls.desktop` file below this point but rather your script file `ls.sh`.

with `ls`, what happens is a terminal opens and your script runs in a shell then your script ends, the shell is terminated and the terminal is closed ... hence any terminal output is gone ... `whiptail` on the other hand keeps waiting for user input and therefore your script hasn't ended yet and thus holding with it the running shell that in turn is holding with it the terminal it's running in.

If you want to see the output, hold the terminal<sup>1</sup> for a certain period of time by e.g. adding a `sleep` call to the end of your script like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ls
sleep 10
```

... or hold it until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> by making it wait for user input like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ls
read
```

... or hold it by replacing the running shell with another interactive shell that you can actually use afterwords like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ls
exec /bin/bash
```

... or hold it with any other means like e.g. with launching a GUI window containing the output of your command like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ls | /bin/zenity --text-info
```

... etc.

---

<sup>1</sup> You're not really holding the terminal but the last running shell in it is ... and unless you explicitly run a terminal in your script with e.g. `gnome-terminal` or similar, your script's output "should" (*generally*) be kept even if from multiple shells and/or sub-shells