# .desktop application won't open a terminal window

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, .desktop

I have a `.desktop` file located in `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keg
Exec=bash -c "ssh -t rpiz 'python3 /home/pi/keg/shell.py'"
Type=Application
Terminal=True
```

The application shows up, and executes, but a terminal window doesn't open.

If I change it to `Exec=bash -c "ssh -t rpiz 'touch ~/hello_from_app'"`, the app creates a file on the remote server, as expected, so I don't think its a permission or authentication issue.

What am I missing?

OS: `Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS 64-bit`

GNOME Version: `42.9`

Comment: "*The application shows up, and executes, but a terminal window doesn't open.*": so what do you see then? Is this `shell.py` something that produces its own GUI? And presumably `rpiz` is a hostname, correct?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at [How to view terminal output from script initiated from .desktop custom application launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/1489698).